# Android Volley posting empty string to php

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I m using Volley by including it in the gradle dependency as

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Now I m posting a string like this

```
word = "{\"question\":\""+answer+"\", \"option\":\""+choice+"\"}";
```

in the request parameters as

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("word", word);
            params.put("uid", String.valueOf(user_id));
            return params;
        }
```

This worked for me for 20 days without any complaints. But suddenly from yesterday users are posting empty string.I checked in the php that `$_POST['word']` is indeed empty. I thought users might be typing double quotes in their input, but this is also not the case as i tested with input without double quotes.This same string I posted using **AsyncHttpResponseHandler** by compiling  `compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'` and it works. This is baffling me. How can a library which works for some days and suddenly stops working for the same input.

**Issue Resolved**
The issue was this: If i recieve the post as simply `$word = $_POST['word'];` i get a valid Json Object and if i recieve as `$word = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['word']);` i get invalid Json Object with escape characters. I had modified the code to latter on a complaint of a user while the issue was his network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this but i will try to help .
You can use "okhttp" http://square.github.io/okhttp/ by adding

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
```

in gradle  and use this code

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("word", word)
                        .addFormDataPart("uid", String.valueOf(user_id))
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://yourwebsite.com/post.php")
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

and remember to use it inside AsyncTask ,
Hope it helps

Comment: I have stated that **AsyncHttpResponseHandler**  works. And so might **OkHttpClient**. But I need to know what exactly happened to volley...